# How to order query results by tag weight in IN('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')

Tags: mysql, query, join, order-by

Consider a simple query as

```
SELECT * FROM posts
JOIN tags USING(post_id)
JOIN tag_map USING(tag_id)
WHERE tags.tag IN('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
```

`tag_map` is a many-to-many relationship between tables `posts` and `tags`.

In this query, mysql will find all posts tagged by any of these words, and order them by PRIMARY KEY.

How can we order the results by tag weight:

1. posts witch tagged with more words in the list (first posts with three tags from the list, then with two words, ...)
2. posts witch tagged with first words (first posts tagged with tag1 then posts tagged with tag2).

Comment: No context or other column names in the question except PKs. I'm assuming `tag_map` is a many<>many relationship between forum/blog posts and tags that have been associated with each post?

Comment: @Phil yes, I added description to clarify the issue.

Comment: "and order them by PRIMARY KEY"  No it won't! There's no ORDER BY so the results won't be ordered.

Comment: Also, with your query a post with 3 tags will be in the resultset 3 times! So you probably want to add a GROUP BY post_id anyway. Then just a COUNT(*) AS cnt in the select and add ORDER BY cnt DESC.

Comment: @Jannes it will not ORDER by PRIMARY KEY, but the results will be retrieved in this order (i.e. order of INSERT). At least in my experience (maybe by chance ;)

Comment: @All PRIMARY KEY has nothing to do with the order of INSERTs. And neither of those has much to do with the retrieval order, even though in practice for very simple it's often the same order as either or both. There are plenty reasons it may not be though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did

```
select * 
from posts p
join tag_map tm on tm.post_id = p.post_id
join tags t on tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
join 
  (select post_id, count(tag_id) as tag_count
   from tag_map
   group by post_id) counts
  on counts.post_id = p.post_id
where t.tag in('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
order by tag_count desc, tag asc
```

and it seems to work OK according to your specs:

1. Order by tag count - I joined with a sub-select that retrieves the tag count per post_id and ordered primarily by that count (descending)
2. Order by tag name - after ordering by tagcount/post, the query orders by tag name

Here's the SQLFiddle if you want to experiment more: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fcd7/9

**Update:** version of the SQLFiddle with index on (tag_map.post_id): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02b5e/1

*PS: this is my first MySQL query, so if there are any criticisms regarding performance/style/anything else, I'd be glad to hear them and learn from them.*

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, but it will not be practical as sub-SELECT is slow.

Comment: @Ali just a guess - perhaps it could be faster with an index on `tag_map.post_id`

Comment: how it can be beneficial? indexes are always good for speed.

Comment: "sub-SELECT is slow" + "indexes are always good for speed" = probably a faster sub-select

Comment: I've made a test with the index. At this data quantity there's obviously no improvement in execution time, but I think the Execution Plan shows an improvement (on the last line). I've added a link to the new SQLFiddle in my post